# What is it called when someone turns into the person they were acting as

Tags: terminology

For example, say an actor was playing a part but then they actually believed that they were that person.

Comment: Please specify that you don't just want hypernyms such as 'delusional'.

Comment: Fake it till you make it? Pygmalion? [Method acting](https://www.city-academy.com/news/what-is-stanislavski-technique/#:~:text=Stanislavski%20Technique%20stems%20from%20his,the%20place%20of%20a%20character.)?

Comment: I believe they called it 'method acting' or 'the method', developed by Stanislavski in the early 20th century.  It's most famous exponent was Marlon Brando.